# Unable to Highlight Text in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a winforms app that initially displays a window with two file dialog boxes, one folder dialog box, and one textbox with some default text in it.  I want the default text to be highlighted.  I've tried everything I have found with no luck.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure HideSelection is false on your textbox and use the select method to select the text:

```
textBox1.HideSelection = false;
textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart) and [SelectionLenght](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength.aspx)

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;
```